# mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.26 の Ver 14.14 のところは何を意味しているのでしょうか？

Tags: mysql, homebrew

brew で入れた MySQL があります。

```
% mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.26, for osx10.10 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

ターミナルでバージョンを確認したところ`Ver 14.14`のが出ているのですが、これは何を意味しているのでしょうか？MySQL自体のバージョンは`5.6.26`と記されたほうだと認識しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL の場合、大抵は「クライアント」と「サーバ」とで分かれており、バージョンを確認した `mysql` はクライアントです (サーバの方は `mysqld` で末尾に **d** が付く)。

"Ver 14.14" の部分がクライアントのバージョン、"Distrib 5.6.26" の部分はクライアントと一緒にビルドされたサーバのバージョンを表しているようです。

参考: "mysql version distrib" での google 検索結果より

[mysqlのバージョン確認について - teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/195956#reply-290469)