# MySQL Utilitiesのmysqldiffのエラー『TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ciphers'』の原因/解決方法

Tags: python, mysql, aws, sql, amazon-linux

#### 環境

OS： Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03(Macからssh接続している)
RDB:DBエンジン Aurora (MySQL 5.6) 1.22.2を使用
※`select version()`した結果5.6.10-log と表示
Python: ver2.6.9
※追記：pyenvにてPython ver3.6.1を導入するも変化なし
mysql-connector-python.x86_64 2.1.7-1.el6 @mysql-connectors-community
※mysql-connectorは `yum list installed | grep mysql-connector-python` にて確認

#### 前提

[MySQL Python connector TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ciphers' - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052965/mysql-python-connector-typeerror-wrap-socket-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argume)は確認済。

#### 問題点

テーブル間の定義の違いを修正する`ALTER`文を生成するために下記のようなコマンドを記入しました。

```
$ mysqldiff \
  --server1=username:password@hostname \
  --difftype=sql \
  --changes-for=server1 \
  --force \
  db1:db2
```

※参考記事：[MySQL (MariaDB) データベース定義の差分を取得する方法](https://qiita.com/shogogg/items/977cf2c7ab3acfba7af8)

そうすると表題のエラーが発生しました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/mysqldiff", line 268, in <module>
    servers = connect_servers(server1_values, server2_values, conn_opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/utilities/common/server.py", line 489, in connect_servers
    source = get_server(src_name, src_dict, quiet, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/utilities/common/server.py", line 336, in get_server
    server_conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/utilities/common/server.py", line 1098, in connect
    self.db_conn = self.get_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/utilities/common/server.py", line 1178, in get_connection
    db_conn = mysql.connector.connect(**parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 728, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 228, in _open_connection
    self._ssl)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 150, in _do_auth
    ssl_options.get('cipher'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 420, in switch_to_ssl
    ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, ciphers=cipher)
TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ciphers'
```

原因として [MySQL Python connector TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ciphers' - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052965/mysql-python-connector-typeerror-wrap-socket-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argume) を参考にMySQL Connector/PythonとPythonのバージョンが合っていない可能性を考えました。

しかし、[MySQL の公式サイト](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-versions.html) を確認したところ、Connector/Python Versionの2.1はPython2.6系をサポートしているようでこれが原因では無いようです...

上記の問題の解決策をご教示お願い致します！
※この情報が足りない！等ありましたらその旨も教えていただけると！

#### ※補足

`yum list installed | grep mysql` した結果

```
mysql-config.x86_64                     5.5.62-1.23.amzn1          @amzn-updates
mysql-connector-python.x86_64           2.1.7-1.el6                @mysql-connectors-community
mysql-utilities.noarch                  1.6.5-1.el6                @mysql-tools-community
mysql55.x86_64                          5.5.62-1.23.amzn1          @amzn-updates
mysql55-libs.x86_64                     5.5.62-1.23.amzn1          @amzn-updates
mysql56.x86_64                          5.6.49-1.37.amzn1          @amzn-updates
mysql56-common.x86_64                   5.6.49-1.37.amzn1          @amzn-updates
mysql56-devel.x86_64                    5.6.49-1.37.amzn1          @amzn-updates
mysql56-errmsg.x86_64                   5.6.49-1.37.amzn1          @amzn-updates
mysql56-libs.x86_64                     5.6.49-1.37.amzn1          @amzn-updates
mysql56-server.x86_64                   5.6.49-1.37.amzn1          @amzn-updates
mysql80-community-release.noarch        el6-3                      installed
php71-mysqlnd.x86_64                    7.1.33-1.43.amzn1          @amzn-updates
php73-mysqlnd.x86_64                    7.3.21-1.28.amzn1          @amzn-updates
```

Comment: 環境の RDB に書かれているのは mysql コマンド (クライアント) の情報なので、mysql**d** (サーバ) とは異なります。 / 参考: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/68291

Comment: ありがとうございます！追記いたしました。

Comment: 参考: [MySQL Python connector TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ciphers'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49056900)

Comment: @metropolis そちらのリンク先は本文中で参照済みのようです。

Comment: エラーメッセージは、質問に書かれているもので全部ですか？
    self._ssl)
    ssl_options.get('cipher'))
    ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, ciphers=cipher)
のように、コードのごく一部だけが示されているのが気になります。

Comment: @Fumu7『Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure』とパスワードのベタ打ちに対しての警告が出ていましたがそこを削っています。それ以外は全てそのまま(のはず)です。

Comment: pyenvを導入してPythonのバージョンを思いっきって3.6.1にまで上げてみましたが変わらずです...(詳細後ほど追記します。)